# javascript - communicate language choice to iframe

Tags: javascript, sessionstorage

I am using the code below to show/hide divs by class, so that when a language is chosen, only the right divs are visible.

This works fine when the language is chosen with the radio buttons, but when a new page is loaded into the iframe, the language preference is not applied to that page. I am trying to use sessionStorage for this, and have gotten as far as communicating the argument to the newly-loaded page within the iframe:

THIS in index.html head to change show/hide in the currently-loaded page when switch is changed:

```
<script>
function setlang(lang) {
    var i;
    var len;
    var list;
    var ifr = document.getElementById('mainframe');
    var cw = (ifr.contentWindow || ifr.contentDocument);

    list = cw.document.getElementsByClassName('langdiv');

    for (i=0, len=list.length ; i<len ; i++){
        list[i].style.display = 'none';
        }

    list = cw.document.getElementsByClassName(lang);

    for (i=0, len=list.length ; i<len ; i++){
        list[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
}

</script>
```

THIS in index.html body to apply new language and save it to sessionStorage:

```
    <div class="switch">
            <input id="english" name="view" type="radio" checked onclick="setlang('EN'); sessionStorage.setItem('language', 'EN');">
            <input id="deutsch" name="view" type="radio" onclick="setlang('DE'); sessionStorage.setItem('language', 'DE');">    
            <input id="francais" name="view" type="radio" onclick="setlang('FR'); sessionStorage.setItem('language', 'FR');">   
            <input id="italiano" name="view" type="radio" onclick="setlang('IT'); sessionStorage.setItem('language', 'IT');">   
    </div>

<div id="iframe"><iframe name="mainframe" id="mainframe" src="home.html"></iframe></div>
```

...and inside a given iframe, I retrieve the sessionStorage argument (this code was used just to make sure that it was working - I have no need to display the sessionStorage argument:

```
<script>
    window.onload=function applylanguagechoice() {
        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        document.getElementById("language").innerHTML = "SELECTED LANGUAGE=" +           sessionStorage.language;
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Rather, I need to use it to show/hide the right div classes, which are organised like this inside the iframe:

```
   <div class="EN languid">Hello</div>
   <div class="DE languid">Guten Tag</div>
   <div class="FR languid">Bonjour</div>
   <div class="IT languid">Ciao</div>
```

As it is now, I have the following (very clumsy in my estimation) code to take the value from sessionStorage:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var selectedlanguage = sessionStorage.getItem("language");

        if (selectedlanguage == 'EN') {
            $('.EN').show();
            $('.DE').hide();
            $('.FR').hide();
            $('.IT').hide();
            } 

        if (selectedlanguage == 'DE') {
            $('.EN').hide();
            $('.DE').show();
            $('.FR').hide();
            $('.IT').hide();
            } 

        if (selectedlanguage == 'FR') {
            $('.EN').hide();
            $('.DE').hide();
            $('.FR').show();
            $('.IT').hide();
            } 

        if (selectedlanguage == 'IT') {
            $('.EN').hide();
            $('.DE').hide();
            $('.FR').hide();
            $('.IT').show();
            } 
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me better take the sessionsStorage argument and apply it to hide/show divs?

THANKS!

Comment: If I understand this right, all of the 4 language specific data would be present on the page and you will just show/hide it based on the language. Won't this make the page heavy? Does the page reload on selection change? If that is the case pass the language as a `queryparam` to the page and load only localization specific content. **Anyway**, your selection logic can be simplified as this: `$('.languid').hide(); $('. ' + selectedlanguage).show();`

Comment: Hey TJ- Yes, it's true that loading all the pages on top of each other could be a bit heavy but the content is pretty much just text, so it doesn't affect performance. Because of this, the page does not reload on selection change (because the necessary div is already present, but invisible)... The reason I did it like this is that there are some not very tech-savvy people who edit the site, and I wanted material in all languages to be in a single file.

Comment: Anyway, isn't sessionStorage a better option than queryparam?

Comment: My intention of using a queryParam was to provide the selectedLanguage to your server that serves the page. `sessionStorage` is available only at the client side (browser) AFAIK. The two serve different purposes.